# Is it possible to run docker-machine and containers on Windows 7 x64 running inside VMware vSphere?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, vsphere

Currently I'm getting VT-X/AMD-V virtualisation is not supported error with default docker-tools installation and virtualbox driver.

"VT-X/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system. Your 64-bit guest will fail to detect a 64-bit CPU and will not able to boot."

Answer (score 0):

Go into your BIOS of you physical machine and enable the VT-X/AMD-V virtualizion option and then try.

But why not just build a Ubuntu-based VM on vsphere and install and run docker there?